Allowing SSH/SFTP access to only part of file system
I want to grant a (remote support) user SSH or SFTP access to the /var/www/html folder (and all sub-folders) on my system.  I don't want them to have access outside this directory.  As well, the ownership of the directories and files in this directory do not match the new user, and I don't want to change the permissions.
This similar question involves setting up a NEW directory with permissions matching the new user.  That's not what I want; I must limit them to an existing directory.  This similar question is close but assumes I can chown the directory to root, which I cannot as apache will fail.
I know how to create a linux user, and I know how to change file/dir permissions, and I understand the concept of chroot.  Just can't figure out how to combine these.

UPDATE: A workarounds seems to be to create a regular SFTP setup and home directory for the user, them mount the desired (target) directory into a subdir of the users home dir, as shown in this post
If there is a better/proper way please post an answer.

ssh or sftp? If ssh, they'd also need access to the shell and whatever command they need to use over ssh.

Actually SFTP would be fine!  (Didn't think of that).  Still unsure of how to do this, but I'll update my question.

Searching for sftp chroot should point you in the right direction.

Possible duplicate of Restricting an SSH/SCP/SFTP user to a directory

The reason you need to restrict permissions on the directory is that theoretically it's possible for them to break out of the chroot jail if they can modify the chroot directory.

That question (and solution) assume that root is the owner of the directory in question.  In my case, the /var/www/html directory must be owned by apache...and I can't change that (without messing up web services)

This question is similar to: Restricting an SSH/SCP/SFTP user to a directory. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@TSG why? Does your web server actually need to write to /var/www/html?

I have requested technical support from a vendor of a WordPress plugin, who needs access to the /var/www/html directory, but for security reasons I want to keep them out of the rest of the system.
